# Dual Monitor not displaying correcly

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, multi-monitor, monitors

I'm a beginner with Linux, I recently installed manjaro as a dual boot on my PC.

I use two screens, but the second one isn't displaying correctly:

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/2549/InXUmb.jpg

I have no idea what's causing this, I don't have this issue when I'm using Windows 10.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this ?